# PHP imap_search work on imap/pop server or locally?

Tags: php, email, imap, mail-server

Consider the scenario in **PHP environment**, I've a mailbox account and I want to process emails in the mailbox. The emails should be processed as per the sender's information.

I came accross the `imap_search` function. Now I've two approaches :

1. Download all the emails and process them one by one.
   *This I want to do only if the `imap_search` function works locally and the search is not executed on the server. **A very lengthy and messed up process.***
2. Download all the emails from particular sender and process them.
   *This should be done if the function `imap_search` works on imap/pop server. **I can separate the processes easily.***

Can somebody please put some light on `imap_search` working?
What do you guys think one should do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

imap_search is a remote search command.  It only works on IMAP (not POP), and is subject to the quality of your IMAP server.  Many "off brand" IMAP servers have poor or non-existent search implementations, so you will have to experiment to see if it is sufficient for you.